# The dual of all bounded and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

For an open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb C$, 
the set of all bounded and analytic functions $f:U \rightarrow \Bbb C$, is a Banach space with 
$\|.\|$$_{\infty}$.  What is the dual of this space?

Thanks for your help...
(Ali, Shahrekord university, Iran)